# Bing Maps v7 - Display TileLayer above Polygon

Tags: bing-maps

I am writing an application that needs to show a variable number of TileLayers and Polygons on a Bing Maps control in an order specified by another application.

Whilst I can get all items to display correctly, the zIndex I set doesn't do as I expect - the polygons appear in the correct order in relation to each other as do the tile layers, but all the tile layers are always below the polygons, e.g.

Expected display order set using zIndex:

- TileLayer 1
- Polygon 1
- TileLayer 2
- Polygon 2

Renders as:

- Polygon 1
- Polygon 2
- TileLayer 1
- TileLayer 2

Is this layout possible using Bing maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polygon layers are vectors, whereas tile layers are rasters. I believe that Bing Maps (and, for that matter, every other web-mapping API that I'm aware of - Google Maps, Leaflet etc.) will always render vector layers on top of raster layers.

Comment: From looking at the HTML generated that's what I was starting to suspect. If I wanted this to work would I have to find a way to render the polygons as a tile layer?